# SSH remote to VBox RaspberryPi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have installed Raspberry Pi on virtual machine, but I can't access to it with putty from another computer. My network adapter 1 is set to NAT and adapter 2 to Host-only adapter. From computer where I have virtual machine I can access to it, but when I want from another computer I can't.

Comment: maybe firewall on your hosting/real machine ? did you try to telnet ip and port from another machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable SSH in the advanced settings of the Raspberry Pi. Then in command line on the Raspberry Pi, type `ip a` to get the IP address of the Raspberry Pi.